# WakeOnLan error

Tags: linux, apt, wake-on-lan, raspbian

I've been working on a wakeonlan script, which worked fine, until now.

Then program wakeonlan, which is not made by me, isn't functioning properly.

When I use **perl -w /usr/bin/wakeonlan** I get this as output:

```
Getopt/Std.pm did not return a true value at /usr/bin/wakeonlan line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/wakeonlan line 10.
```

The first 10 lines of **/usr/bin/wakeonlan**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# $Id: wakeonlan,v 1.4.2.3 2005/01/27 16:03:54 jpo Exp $
#
#########################################################################       

use strict;
use Net::hostent;
use Socket;
use Getopt::Std;
```

I erased wakeonlan and installed it again, but it gives the same error.

I was not able to find any clear solution on Google. Maybe some of you guys know what the problem can be?

Comment: What's the full command you use? wakeonlan needs arguments. Also, you can just run `wakeonlan` no need for `perl -w /usr/bin`

Comment: You sure you have correctly installed all the perl modules? How did you installed wakeonlan?

Comment: Have you made any changes to `Getopt/Std.pm`? It should be in `/usr/share/perl/$PERL_VERSION/Getopt/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable reason for this error is that the `Getopt/Std.pm` library is damaged on your system. Try to locate it, for example with `locate Std.pm`; on my system, it's located here:

```
iserv ~ # locate Std.pm
/usr/share/perl/5.10.1/Getopt/Std.pm
```

Try to open it with an editor. It is 295 lines long on my system and it has to end with the line `1;`. If the file is damaged or empty, you need to reinstall the package that provides this file (`perl-modules` on Debian).

Comment: Can you describe how exactly you fixed the error? Would be nice to have that for future reference.